# Install devtools package in ubuntu VM

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, devtools

I try to install devtools package in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM
in which I am wrong.

Other packages I tried the installed successsfully

However I can't install it and the process in the console is this:

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’, ‘httr’, ‘git2r’

--2018-01-26 22:14:08--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/curl_3.1.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 366086 (358K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/curl_3.1.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13% 1017K 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 27% 1,62M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41% 1,32M 0s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55% 4,09M 0s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69% 4,59M 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83% 12,0M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97% 2,84M 0s
   350K .......                                               100% 19,6M=0,2s

2018-01-26 22:14:09 (2,18 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/curl_3.1.tar.gz’ saved [366086/366086]

--2018-01-26 22:14:09--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_0.9.9.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1112927 (1,1M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/openssl_0.9.9.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 1,02M 1s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  194K 3s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  215K 3s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18%  227K 3s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23% 10,2M 3s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 27%  253K 3s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32%  271K 2s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  289K 2s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  317K 2s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46% 3,97M 2s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50%  338K 2s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55%  346K 1s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%  372K 1s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64% 5,58M 1s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  317K 1s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  315K 1s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%  344K 1s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82%  344K 1s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87% 6,08M 0s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  404K 0s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 96%  567K 0s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... ......               100% 7,47M=2,8s

2018-01-26 22:14:13 (394 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/openssl_0.9.9.tar.gz’ saved [1112927/1112927]

--2018-01-26 22:14:13--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.3.1.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 147593 (144K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/httr_1.3.1.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 34%  934K 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  100K 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ....      100%  342K=0,7s

2018-01-26 22:14:15 (212 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/httr_1.3.1.tar.gz’ saved [147593/147593]

--2018-01-26 22:14:15--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/git2r_0.21.0.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1155512 (1,1M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/git2r_0.21.0.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 1,06M 1s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8% 1,52M 1s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13% 1,28M 1s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 17% 1,54M 1s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22% 6,96M 1s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 1,10M 1s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31% 1,21M 1s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35%  940K 1s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39% 1,72M 0s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 44% 5,84M 0s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 48% 1,38M 0s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53% 2,17M 0s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57% 2,20M 0s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62% 5,09M 0s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66% 2,36M 0s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 70% 3,40M 0s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75% 1,73M 0s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79% 2,03M 0s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 84% 42,4M 0s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88% 2,49M 0s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93% 1,68M 0s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97% 3,40M 0s
  1100K .......... .......... ........                        100% 83,9M=0,6s

2018-01-26 22:14:16 (1,93 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/git2r_0.21.0.tar.gz’ saved [1155512/1155512]

--2018-01-26 22:14:16--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 486348 (475K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10% 1,10M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21% 1,40M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31% 1,54M 0s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 1,72M 0s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52% 2,99M 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 63% 1,54M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  867K 0s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 84% 2,16M 0s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 94% 3,66M 0s
   450K .......... .......... ....                            100% 8,73M=0,3s

2018-01-26 22:14:17 (1,63 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages/devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz’ saved [486348/486348]

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘git2r’ ...
** package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking size of void*... 8
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for library containing EVP_EncryptInit... no
checking for openssl... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpQ9e11v/R.INSTALL82977388520/git2r':
configure: error: 
  ---------------------------------------------
   The OpenSSL library that is required to
   build git2r was not found.

   Please install:
     libssl-dev    (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     openssl-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
     openssl       (Homebrew package on OS X)
   and try again.

   If the OpenSSL library is installed on
   your system but the git2r configuration
   is unable to find it, you can specify
   the include and lib path to OpenSSL with:
   R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-libssl-include=INCLUDE_PATH --with-libssl-lib=LIB_PATH' git2r
  ---------------------------------------------
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/git2r’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/downloaded_packages’
```

Any idea how could I install it? The problem is the same if I use instead of Rstudio I use the terminal for R

Also installing car package from github, as I can't find it in the list of Tools->Install Packages has problem:

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github("cran/car")
Downloading GitHub repo cran/car@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/cran/car/zipball/master
Installing car
--2018-01-26 22:39:07--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pbkrtest_0.4-7.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 156406 (153K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/pbkrtest_0.4-7.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32% 1,16M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65% 1,45M 0s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98% 3,79M 0s
   150K ..                                                    100% 8,52M=0,09s

2018-01-26 22:39:07 (1,68 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/pbkrtest_0.4-7.tar.gz’ saved [156406/156406]

Installing pbkrtest
--2018-01-26 22:39:11--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-15.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3610706 (3,4M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/lme4_1.1-15.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 1,05M 3s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2% 1,52M 3s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4% 3,40M 2s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5% 1,36M 2s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7% 3,97M 2s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8% 15,4M 2s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9% 2,23M 2s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11% 65,5M 1s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12% 3,85M 1s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14% 60,4M 1s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15% 79,4M 1s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 17% 6,83M 1s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18% 2,60M 1s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19% 4,68M 1s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21% 83,6M 1s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22% 91,2M 1s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24% 96,8M 1s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 25% 4,27M 1s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 91,6M 1s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28% 1,39M 1s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 29% 3,98M 1s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31% 27,1M 1s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32% 91,8M 1s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 34% 86,4M 1s
  1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35% 3,19M 1s
  1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36% 5,66M 1s
  1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38% 43,6M 0s
  1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 39% 86,1M 0s
  1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41% 5,28M 0s
  1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42% 16,6M 0s
  1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 9,84M 0s
  1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45% 3,84M 0s
  1600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 46% 4,36M 0s
  1650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 48% 19,5M 0s
  1700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49% 4,09M 0s
  1750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 51% 84,7M 0s
  1800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52% 1,32M 0s
  1850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53%  104M 0s
  1900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55% 14,4M 0s
  1950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56% 23,1M 0s
  2000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 58% 3,18M 0s
  2050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59% 2,28M 0s
  2100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 60%  103M 0s
  2150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62% 2,08M 0s
  2200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 63% 13,6M 0s
  2250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65% 3,23M 0s
  2300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66% 4,50M 0s
  2350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68% 13,9M 0s
  2400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69% 98,1M 0s
  2450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 70% 42,6M 0s
  2500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72% 4,12M 0s
  2550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73% 17,2M 0s
  2600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75% 73,7M 0s
  2650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76% 94,0M 0s
  2700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 77%  102M 0s
  2750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79% 80,8M 0s
  2800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80%  101M 0s
  2850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82% 3,39M 0s
  2900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83% 89,8M 0s
  2950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85% 88,7M 0s
  3000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86% 82,8M 0s
  3050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87% 7,12M 0s
  3100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 89% 80,9M 0s
  3150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90% 79,9M 0s
  3200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92% 7,38M 0s
  3250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93%  100M 0s
  3300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95% 88,2M 0s
  3350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 96% 9,04M 0s
  3400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97% 11,9M 0s
  3450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 99,2M 0s
  3500K .......... .......... ......                          100% 97,2M=0,6s

2018-01-26 22:39:12 (6,14 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/lme4_1.1-15.tar.gz’ saved [3610706/3610706]

Installing lme4
--2018-01-26 22:39:20--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 54.230.27.181
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|54.230.27.181|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 353957 (346K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14% 1,11M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%  106K 1s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43%  644K 1s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  677K 0s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 72% 5,64M 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86%  628K 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .....     100% 2,39M=0,8s

2018-01-26 22:39:22 (448 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz’ saved [353957/353957]

Installing nloptr
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/devtools756410ec724/nloptr' --library='/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2' --install-tests 

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-nloptr’
Installation failed: Command failed (3)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/devtools7561eb5da54/lme4'  \
  --library='/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘nloptr’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lme4’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/devtools75623bf595c/pbkrtest' --library='/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pbkrtest’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/tmp/RtmpIF4wAz/devtools75635e8f138/cran-car-4f39fce' --library='/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2' --install-tests 

ERROR: dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/car’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Certainly, the answer is within the output you pasted. You need to install in the OS (as opposed as in R) the following dependencies:

libcurl4-openssl-dev
libssl-dev

To install them, run in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

And then go to R and try reinstalling "devtools".

Comment: thank you. it works. As I am new in Ubuntu just a silly question. You understood what is missing based on the ANTICONF ERROR it refer? Because after that there was other error additionally due to the lack of that

Comment: I ask this because I have also problem to install car package as I can find in the list so I tried github option but again it is not working. After the installations you mentioned for devtools. Any hind will be very helpful for me

Comment: I did understand it from the output of devtools, but just because two of devtools dependencies (rcurl and git2r) tell us straight away which libraries they could not find in the OS.
This is not the norm, it is rather the exception. Most packages will let you high and dry.

Comment: Thank you I understand. Any idea for the trace of car package because this is the package I tried to install using devtools

Comment: 3 questions to help you solve the issue:

1. Are you sure car was not installed by default along with the whole R package? What happens when you run library(car) on a clean R installation?
2. What version of R are you running?
3. Did you install r-base-dev along r-base in Ubuntu?

Comment: 1) yes I am sure because when I type `library(car)` I receive this error `Error in library(car) there is no package called 'car'` 2) I use 3.2.3 version 3) I have installed it.

Comment: I see... What happens if you run in R's console
install.packages('car')? 
I just ran it in a freshly installed lubuntu VM and worked.

Comment: Thank you I made a new question for this and add the error I receive if I install it with the way you mention from R console from terminal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470170/car-package-in-ubuntu-machine-16-04

Answer (score 3):

As of Ubuntu 20.0 devtools is available as a r-cran ubuntu package.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/r-cran-devtools

Install with `sudo apt-get install r-cran-devtools`

Comment: This also works in kali linux and presumably other debian based linux distros

Answer (score 1):

Guess you need to add 
`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` 
also. This is because devtools require the package xml2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 worked for me:

```
apt-get install libzmq3-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev
```