# car package in Ubuntu machine 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I can't install car package in R in an Ubuntu VM 16.04.

My last attempt was through terminal console of R.

The same result when I try to run it through R studio or using devtools

I receive the following errors:

```
> install.packages('car')
Installing package into ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
also installing the dependencies ‘nloptr’, ‘lme4’, ‘pbkrtest’

trying URL 'https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib/nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 353957 bytes (345 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 345 KB

trying URL 'https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-15.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3610706 bytes (3.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.4 MB

trying URL 'https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib/pbkrtest_0.4-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 156406 bytes (152 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib/car_2.1-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 627349 bytes (612 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 612 KB

ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-nloptr’
ERROR: dependency ‘nloptr’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lme4’
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘pbkrtest’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pbkrtest’
ERROR: dependency ‘pbkrtest’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/car’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXR2ZjI/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("car") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("car") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("car") :
  installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("car") :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143608/failed-to-lock-directory-when-installing-r-package-using-devtoolsinstall-githu I think technically this is a duplicate, but the answer on that question is in the comments rather than in answer form. Either way, I think the solution mentioned by nrussell in the comments there might work.

Comment: It is telling you that it could not install the dependencies ‘nloptr’, 'lme4', 'pbkrtest'.

Try install.packages(nloptr', repos = 'https://cran.univ-paris1.fr')
install.packages('lme4', repos = 'https://cran.univ-paris1.fr')
install.packages('pbkrtest', repos = 'https://cran.univ-paris1.fr')

in order to identify the one that is not installing properly.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez The reason it couldn't install the dependencies was because it couldn't install `nloptr`, for the reason stated in the error message: `failed to lock directory ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’`. The error message also suggests a solution: `Try removing ‘/home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-nloptr’`. That's the issue discussed in the other question I linked.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez thank you I tried the first package nloptr and it says it is not available for R version 3.2.3

Comment: @duckmayr thank you please could you type one more time the command because I can't run it properly. Also should I run it with sudo in terminal or in R console?

Comment: Well, R 3.2 dates from 2015 or so... 
Perhaps the current package is no longer compatible. You might want to update your R. Look here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-ubuntu-16-04-xenial/

Comment: @LenaKosta I would open a terminal (since you're using Ubuntu, you can do so using Ctrl-Alt-T) and use the following command `rm -rf /home/stefan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/00LOCK-nlopt‌​r`. There should be no need to run with `sudo`. I also agree with Nicolás Velásquez that you should update your version of R considering how old that version is.

Comment: thank you both finally the update to a newer version was the solution